# Flutter : No consume Correctamente mi API de manera Local

Tags: laravel, api, flutter, laravel-8, programación-móvil

Estoy intentando consumir un API localmente de Laravel, en flutter , tengo el consumo de los endpoints separados en el archivo de app_constants.dart, pero flutter al momento de mandar la solicitud GET hacia la API de laravel, no logra encontrar correctamente el PATH, ya que como está indicado el archivo, estoy llamando a la ruta estática ("http://127.0.0.1:8000/") , y al hacer la petición GET flutter hace un switch de puertos,  al 46656,46658,46660 como lo muestro la imagen, entonces flutter lo interpretá de la siguiente forma =>("http://127.0.0.1:46656/"),y por ello no me consume en especifico las imagenes, por que espera encontrarla con el PATH pero en el puerto 8000 que es por defecto el de laravel, como podría solucionarlo?

Dejo mis un mi archivo de dart y el .env de laravel

Flutter:

```
class AppConstants{
  //cambiar el nombre de la app en algun futuro , con otro proyecto
  static const String APP_NAME = 'DBFood';
  static const int APP_VERSION = 1;

  static const String BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';
  static const String POPULAR_PRODUCT_URI = 'api/v1/products/popular';
  static const String RECOMMENDED_PRODUCT_URI = 'api/v1/products/recommended';
  static const String UPLOAD_URL = 'uploads/';

  static const String TOKEN = 'DBToken';

  static const String CART_LIST = 'cart-list';

  static const String CART_HISTORY_LIST = 'cart-history-list';
}
```

Laravel:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:WCPyXwmMZszSnG1mbDTw4jywbcL4XXv0NW0zPSZD7ok=
APP_DEBUG=true
FORCE_HTTPS = false
ADMIN_HTTPS = false
APP_URL= http://127.0.0.1:8000/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=shopping
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

E intentando modificar el archivo env, agregando el alias de loacalhost al PATH, tampoco, eh intentando modificar los soquets  en los archivos de xamp , tampoco..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te estás conectando desde Android vas a tener problemas para acceder al servidor en tu local. Para solucionar esto lo que tienes que hacer es cambiar ```localhost``` por ```10.0.2.2```. Si no te funciona también puedes intentar entrar a la configuración de wifi de tu pc y obtener la ip pública de este, y de la misma manera reemplazar ```localhost``` por la ip que obtengas

Comment: así es, estoy desarrollando en dispositivo físico, crees que si me cambio a un emulador , solucione el dilema?